# Angular validation ng-invalid .NET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

In the following sample of code, I am creating a form field in .NET enviroment:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="friendlyname" class="col-md-3 text-align-right"><strong>Friendly Name</strong></label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input name="friendlyname"
                   id="friendlyname"
                   type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   maxlength="80"
                   placeholder="Enter a friendly name here..."
                   autocomplete="off"
                   ng-model="EventDetails.friendlyname"
                   ng-change="SaveEventDetails()"
                   ng-blur="SaveEventDetails()">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
```

Reading the Angular validations documentation, I am trying to specify that this field should contains only alphabet and gaps (no numbers).

I am not sure on how exactly should I use $dirty or $invalid in case to proceed.

Any help is welcome.
Thank you!

Comment: use pattern to validate this input

Comment: Although I found `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/"` , that could be used for my purpose,  I do not know how to print an error message for an invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

First look documentation FormController
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

In last section you have error

> Is an object hash, containing references to controls or forms with
>   failing
>
> - validators, where: keys are validation tokens (error names)
> - values are arrays of controls or forms that have a failing validator    for    given error name.

To print error you must access to error and check your error names is true

Example from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

```
<input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="uEmail" required="" />
    <br />
    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uEmail.$touched">
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required">Tell us your email.</span>
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
    </div>
```

Where `form` is form name `uEmail` input name. You can use `ng-messages` for more options
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages
If you want style form you can use bootstrap class
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

Answer (score 0):

you can used `ng-pattern` to specify that you only want alphabetics character.

Then you can use `ng-title` with the $invalid boolean of your input that allow you to display the text of the input when your form is invalid.